# making a small tick mark across y-axis and annotating it with a text in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a figure with a small tick mark across a particular point in y - axis and label that point. Here is a sample plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(10),
                   'y': np.arange(100, 200, 10)})

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(4.5,4.5))
ax.plot(df.x,df.y)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(100,200)

plt.annotate(r'$y_{i}$',\
             xy = (0.2,150),
             xytext = (-0.75,150))          

ax.axhline(y=150, xmin=0, xmax=0.02)
plt.savefig("plot/sample plot.png", dpi = 1000)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

with this code I could produce following plot:
[image]

However, I want the tick marks across the y-axis as follows:
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the artist outside of the Axes is clipped, you can set `clip_on` to False, and set `xmin` to a negative value, such as:

```py
ax.axhline(y=150, xmin=-0.02, xmax=0.02, clip_on=False)
```